# WebStorm CSS unit selection suggestion 1st choice

Tags: autocomplete, workflow, webstorm

I tried googling for this, but could not find anything on it by myself.

When you type out something that has auto suggestions in WebStorm, like `<d..` then the auto complete box with suggestions comes up, and the first element is selected; and if I want to select it I only have to press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image]

but when I try to do the same when writing CSS, and typing something like `width: 1` the suggestions pop up like usual, but WebStorm doesn't select the top suggestion.

[image]

I figure might have to do with the fact that there are different types of suggestions available, not just numeric values, and then a denomination/value type.

If there is a plugin, or a setting I could use/change, it would be very nice if someone could point me to it. As tapping that arrow down once every time I want to select the most relevant/top result is just a little bit annoying when you are already in the habit of just hitting enter when having typed a value.

Please feel free to let me know if you need any more information, or if I have made a duplicate, or some other error, and I will append or fix it to the best of my abilities.

Comment: Thank you SuperDJ for embedding the images :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's done on purpose. Preselection of the first unit in the completion list will make it impossible to type fractional numbers because typing dot would insert the preselected completion item. Also, a unit would be inserted on typing Space, which would make it difficult to type a number without a unit.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. I guess the whole workflow for auto completing would have to be changed for something like that(pressing enter, that is) to be implemented then, and now that I know tab can be used there wouldn't be much point to it.

Answer (score 0):

Logged as [WEB-35552](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-35552), please vote for it to be notified on any progress; note that you can insert the first item by hitting `Tab`